# I can't access my email in Outllok 2021, it always ask password

Tags: microsoft-outlook, passwords, office365

Since one month I have problem with Outlook. I search everywhere but I only found simple solution that doesn't help. I use Outlook 2021 (not O365) with 2 account Office 365 (2 different tenant) and some imap, pop3 and gmail accounts.

My problem is everyday when I start Outlook, he ask me for password (and MFA too) for my 2 Office 365 accounts, that's not a big deal yet, but after it said at the bottom 'password required'. And it start, I reenter password, do MFA, and still required password. I stop Outlook, delete Credential (OAUTH) in credential manager, and retry. And again until it work. Sometime 1 account begin working the other not. I take me 15-30 mins each morning to got access. At the beginning it asked me only when I started outlook but now it is a real pain. And sometime during the day it ask me one time my password again.

I tried so much thing that I cant list all of it here. Now the last resort is to reset my Windows profile and I don't want to do that because I have so much configuration in it. It will take one day to reconfigure it.

Here a list of what I've done, none of them helped:

- I created a new profile with only 1 O365 account.
- I added to registry : [HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Office\16.0\Outlook\AutoDiscover] "ExcludeExplicitO365Endpoint"=dword:00000001
- I added to registry : [HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Exchange] "AlwaysUseMSOAuthForAutoDiscover"=dword:00000001 (This one make a windows flashing in Outlook)
- I tried the autofix by Microsoft
- Removed and reconfigured O365 account in Outlook
- And many others

One thing seem to help, I connect to one of my O365 account via outlook.com and after I have no problem with Outlook for this account. Outlook stop asking me for password in a loop for this account.

Does somebody have any suggestion before I reset my Windows profile?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the Outlook profile, or an alternative, create a new profile and use profile temporally.

Comment: @Ramhound : It is my 1st lane in my tryout list. I didn't delete my profile. But I created new profile with one of my O365 account. I had the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't have choice, I reset my Windows profile. After that everything worked fine, until I add some POP3 email account. After that, the problem come back. So I deleted all POP3 account but it didn't correct the problem. I use the Microsoft repair tool but it didn't correct it. I had to reset my profile again. Now I used IMAP access to these account and the problem didn't come back.

Using POP3 is now deprecated by most email systems. MS-Exchange disabled basic auth since 1st october 2022. So probably there are problem between basic auth and Office 365 account and both can't coexist in the same user profile.

Answer (score -1):

What about configuring your two accounts to two separate profiles?

Please try to remove the current Outlook profile and remove credentials related to your two accounts in Credential Manager. And then create a new profile and add your accounts to check if there're any differences.

In addition, there's an article about password prompting, please refer to this: [Outlook continually prompts for your password when you try to connect to Microsoft 365](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook/troubleshoot/authentication/continually-prompts-password-office-365).

Comment: I need both account in the same profile because I receive urgent email from both account and I will always have to switch between them. I tried delete credential and create new profile (without deleting original one) with one of my 0365 account and I had same problem

Comment: Have you tried the suggestions in the article as mentioned in my last reply?

Comment: Yes I read it but it applies to Outlook 2013 or less. I have 2021. I still check the Anonymous Authentication setting and it doesn't exist in my version and it doesn't exist in the registry either.

Comment: Do you mean that you tried the solution in this article?(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/outlook/troubleshoot/authentication/outlook-prompt-password-modern-authentication-enabled) If so, please create the registry path manually to check if there're any differences.

Comment: Just checking in to see if above information was helpful. If you have any further updates on this issue, please feel free to post back. If you think my reply is helpful to you, please remember to mark it as an answer. Warm thanks.

Comment: I tried it to create it manually but it didn't help